# How can I prevent this recursive function from exceeding the maximum callstack?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recursion

I need to build a 50x50 grid and thought rather than typing it all out I'd write a recursive function to fill it into a constant but now it's exceeding the maximum callstack.

```
import { CellState } from "./types";

const InitialCellsState = (): CellState[] => {
const cellsState: CellState[] = [{ columnIndex: 1, rowIndex: 1 }];

function addCellByRow(cell: CellState) {
    cellsState.push(cell);
    if (cell.rowIndex === 50) {
        if (cell.columnIndex === 50) {
            return;
        }
        addCellByRow({ columnIndex: cell.columnIndex + 1, rowIndex: 1 });
    }
    addCellByRow({ columnIndex: cell.columnIndex, rowIndex: cell.rowIndex + 1 });
}

   addCellByRow(cellsState[0]);

   return cellsState;
};

export default InitialCellsState;
```

Is it infinitely looping or just too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use recursion here at all? You're just introducing method-call overhead where it's not necessary!

```
import { CellState } from "./types";

const InitialCellsState = (): CellState[] => {
    const cellsState: CellState[] = [];
    for(var col = 1; col <= 50; col++){
        for(var row = 1; row <=50; row++){
            cellsState.push({ columnIndex: col, rowIndex: row })
        }    
    }
    return cellState;
}
```

In case you were wondering, your recursive function was only exiting out if *both* row AND col were equal 50. Which means the first row goes on for ever.

Answer (score 0):

Regular loops would probably be more efficient than recursion but this would do the trick...

```js
interface CellState {
  columnIndex: number;
  rowIndex: number;
}

const InitialCellsState = (): CellState[] => {
  const cellsState: CellState[] = [];

  function addCellByRow(cell: CellState) {
    cellsState.push(cell);
    if (cell.rowIndex === 50) {
      // you dont need to handle a case you're just going to return anyway
      if (cell.columnIndex !== 50) { 
        addCellByRow({ columnIndex: cell.columnIndex + 1, rowIndex: 1 });
      }
    } else { // not using an else will cause it to keep adding duplicates
      addCellByRow({
        columnIndex: cell.columnIndex,
        rowIndex: cell.rowIndex + 1
      });
    }
  }

  // don't populate the cellsstate with a starting value because you'll be adding a duplicate that way
  addCellByRow({ columnIndex: 1, rowIndex: 1 });

  return cellsState;
};

export default InitialCellsState;
```